# Error attempting to send OFX HTTP POST with PHP cURL

Tags: php, curl, ofx

I have plans to build a my own financial management application for personal use.  I have enabled the direct connect service through Chase but I am having some issues getting a response from the server.  Here is the code that I am using.  Someone was nice enough to post this on another forum for others to use.

```
<?php

// this function is just used to generate a random transaction id below
function getRandomString($length = 40, $charset = 'alphanum') {
$alpha = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$num = '0123456789';
switch ($charset) {
    case 'alpha':
        $chars = $alpha;
        break;
    case 'alphanum':
        $chars = $alpha . $num;
        break;
    case 'num':
        $chars = $num;
        break;            
}

$randstring='';
$maxvalue=strlen($chars)-1;
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
  $randstring .= substr($chars, rand(0, $maxvalue), 1);
return $randstring;
}

// user login info
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

// account info
$accnt_num = '00000000';
$accnt_type = 'CHECKING';

// date and a random unique transaction id
$txn_id = getRandomString(6);
$tz_offset = date('Z')/3600;
$date = date("YmdHis[$tz_offset:T]");

// Chase info
$org = 'B1';
$fid = '10898';
$bank_id = '122100024';

// transaction retrieval date range
$start_date = '20090101000000';        // from date, to..
$end_date = date('YmdHis');        // now

$xml = "
<OFX>
    <SIGNONMSGSRQV1>
    <SONRQ>
        <DTCLIENT>$date</DTCLIENT>
        <USERID>$user</USERID>
        <USERPASS>$pass</USERPASS>
        <LANGUAGE>ENG</LANGUAGE>
        <FI>
            <ORG>$org</ORG>
            <FID>$fid</FID>
        </FI>
        <APPID>QWIN</APPID>
        <APPVER>2200</APPVER>
    </SONRQ>
</SIGNONMSGSRQV1>

<BANKMSGSRQV1>
    <STMTTRNRQ>
        <TRNUID>$txn_id</TRNUID>
        <STMTRQ>
            <BANKACCTFROM>
                <BANKID>$bank_id</BANKID>
                <ACCTID>$accnt_num</ACCTID>
                <ACCTTYPE>$accnt_type</ACCTTYPE>
            </BANKACCTFROM>
            <INCTRAN>
                <DTSTART>$start_date</DTSTART>
                <DTEND>$end_date</DTEND>
                <INCLUDE>Y</INCLUDE>
            </INCTRAN>
        </STMTRQ>
    </STMTTRNRQ>
</BANKMSGSRQV1>
</OFX>";

$ch = curl_init();
$ch1 = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ofx.chase.com');
$ch2 = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$ch3 = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
$ch4 = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$ch5 = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$ch6 = curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result) {
    echo $result;
}
    else
echo "<pre>CURL ERROR: " . curl_error($ch) . "</pre>";
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

I get the following message when trying to run this from my browser.

```
CURL ERROR: SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 0
```

I saw in another post that you may need to update the cacert.pem certificate so I downloaded the new one and added this to my php.ini file but it didn't help.

```
curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\PHP\cacert.pem"
```

If I use curl_errno instead of curl_error I get a curl error code of 56 which is CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56) Failure with receiving network data.

I know that the chase server is available for OFX download as I am able to get my banking info through the GNUCash financial manager.  Any help someone could offer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

i've recently been doing something similar and for reasons i really can't explain quite yet, i couldn't get the same code snippet you're using to work either. i did however have immediate luck with [this php library](https://github.com/denvertimothy/OFX/blob/master/OFX.php). you'll result with a $finance object that is nice and neat. i hacked the account class to have a `$transactions` property that I later fill with the transactions since that information is available from the OFX request that was already made.

I added this to the end of Account->setup()

```
    ...
    $a = $x->xpath('/OFX/*/*/*/AVAILBAL/BALAMT');
    if(isset($a[0]))
        $this->availableBalance = (double)$a[0];

// added code below
    if($this->type == 'BANK')
        $this->transactions = $x->xpath('/OFX/BANKMSGSRSV1/STMTTRNRS/STMTRS/BANKTRANLIST/STMTTRN');
    elseif($this->type == 'CC')
        $this->transactions = $x->xpath('/OFX/CREDITCARDMSGSRSV1/CCSTMTTRNRS/CCSTMTRS/BANKTRANLIST/STMTTRN');
```

hope this helps!